# API to convert documents from doc to docx in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office

I need to convert all documents of sharepoint online library without losing any document properties and without changing the ID of the item. Is there any method to do this?
I checked [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16825/can-i-upgrade-doc-to-docx-in-place-in-a-doc-library) but it is using Office Interop library which is not available in Sharepoint online