# Convert SharePoint document from doc to docx - and keep version history

Tags: version-history, version, document-converter

I need to convert a large amount of .doc documents to .docx

The issue is that by doing so I am changing the file name, and with it - losing the file number, history and properties.

Is there any way to perform the conversion without losing these (when the file history is the most important)?

Thanks,
Roni

Comment: It's possible. See the client object model solution from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16825/can-i-upgrade-doc-to-docx-in-place-in-a-doc-library/16926#16926).